# kissXML parse an xml file as a tree

Tags: objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

```
<book>
<index num="1">
    <item key="0" xPos="100" yPos="214"/>
    <item key="14" xPos="100" yPos="250"/>
    <item key="28" xPos="100" yPos="286"/>

</index>
<index num="2">
    <item key="146" xPos="100" yPos="134"/>
    <item key="149" xPos="100" yPos="170"/>
</index>
<index num="3">
    <item key="234" xPos="100" yPos="134"/>
</index>
```

i want use kissXML to parse this file

ie.

if num=1 only parse key= 0、14、28  and put them into an NSArray keyArray

if num=2 only parse key= 146、149  and put them into an NSArray keyArray

my code:

```
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"xml"];
NSError* error = nil; 
NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
DDXMLDocument *xmlDoc = [[DDXMLDocument alloc]initWithXMLString:xmlString options:0 error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
xmlString = nil;

NSArray* resultNodes_1 = nil;
resultNodes_1 = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//index" error:&error];

NSArray* resultNodes = nil;
resultNodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//item" error:&error];    

for(DDXMLElement* resultElement_1 in resultNodes_1)
{
    NSString* keyVal_1 = [[resultElement_1 attributeForName:@"num"] stringValue];
    NSMutableArray *key_1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [key_1 addObject:keyVal_1];
    [resultElement_1 childCount];
```

//        NSLog(@"index: %d",[resultElement_1 childCount]);
        if ([keyVal_1 isEqual:@"1"]) {

```
        for(DDXMLElement* resultElement in resultNodes)
        {

            NSString* keyVal = [[resultElement attributeForName:@"key"] stringValue];
            NSMutableArray *keyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [keyArray addObject:keyVal];

            NSString* xPosVal = [[resultElement attributeForName:@"xPos"] stringValue];
            NSMutableArray *xPosArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [xPosArray addObject:xPosVal];

            NSString* yPosVal = [[resultElement attributeForName:@"yPos"] stringValue];
            NSMutableArray *yPosArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [yPosArray addObject:yPosVal];

             NSLog(@"key的值为:%@",keyVal);

        }
    }
}
```

from my code i want the result was key ----0、14、28

but the result is: key----0、14、28、146、149、234  print all key value

help me,plese

Comment: For what you describe you want, a SAX parser seems more appropriate (NSXMLParser). Do you have a reason to use XPath?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to go to the trouble of using xpath to do this anyway, you could just build a complete xpath expression and gather the data that way.

For example,

```
[xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//index[@num="2"]/item" error:&error];
```

Will return just the item nodes under index where num is 2.

So, you could build this path by using:

```
NSString *xpathPattern=
    [NSString stringWithFormat: @"//index[@num=\"%d\"]/item", desiredValue];
NSArray* resultNodes = nil;
resultNodes = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath: xpathPattern error:&error];
```

And pass your desired value to that.   At this point, you now have just:

```
<item key="0" xPos="100" yPos="214"/>
<item key="14" xPos="100" yPos="250"/>
<item key="28" xPos="100" yPos="286"/>
```

If you send in desiredValue = 1, and you can then pull out the key, xPos, and yPos as you have already defined in your inner loop.